# Laravel project throw an error 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel

i am getting an `error 404 not found` when accessing `home.blade.php`  located in resources/views

here's the controller  called `postsController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class postsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    public function index(): View
    {
        //$posts = DB::table('posts')->get();
 
        return view('home.index', ['users' => $posts]);
    }
}
```

and the other file looks are

routes in web.php

```
Route::get('/home', [PostsController::class, 'index'])->name('home.index');
```

portion of codes in `home.blade.php` for displaying all posts

```
 <h1>Posts</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <li>
            {{ $post->title }} - {{ $post->body }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

what's wrong with the above code ? and how can routes be written correctly to access the desired locations? i.e `home.blade.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blade.php` is only to be used as a file extension for the source code of your templates, it should never really be used in your code and it should never be used by your users.

`home.blade.php` is not a route, that is just a template file for `Blade`

`resources/views` is just a "source code" folder, it should never be accessed directly from the browser

in your browser you would do `example.com/home` and NOT `example.com/home.blade.php`

in your controller you would call the view like this

```php
// 'home' is the name of the view
return view('home', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

in a different controller method you might want to do something like this

```php
// 'home.index' is the name of the route
return redirect()->route('home.index');
```

Comment: no need to define a route for it?

Comment: You do need to define a route. There was nothing wrong with your router definition. I am only correcting your controller

Answer (score 1):

class `postsController` extends Controller

Route::get('/home', [`PostsController`::class, 'index'])->name('home.index');

1. Inconsistent controller names.
   you've different controller name in controller file and route,it should be same,  while the naming convention for controller is it should be singular and in camel case. e.g: PostController
2. return view('home.index', ['users' => $posts]);
   for returnig the blade file name only to return the view. e.g: 'home'
3. return view('home.index', [`'users' => $posts`]);
   you're passing the variable names users to the view but in view you're iterating the loop over `$post`.